# Dual boot windows 8 with UBUNTU on Dell Inspiron 3543

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

Recently I have purchased a Dell Inspiron 3000 series laptop(Model: Inspiron 3543) with Win 8.1 preloaded. I want to install UBUNTU in dual boot mode with Win8. Kindly guide me how to go about? Please provide me the solution ASAP.

Regards
Rupin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

If you type "dual boot windows 8 linux" into a search engine there are a host of articles who'll guide you. This one worked for me:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

To make the live USB, I used LinuxLive USB Creator, though there are others to choose from too.

Then, in step 4 of the instructions in the article, to turn of the secure boot I found it under the "advanced" tab, inside "boot settings". Note though that this is different for different setups.

Good luck!